# I can't remove the entire column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
--data.csv file
ID,Index,Height,Weight
0,1,167,51
1,2,181,61
2,3,176,69
3,4,173,64
4,5,172,65
--data.csv file

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

I want to remove "ID" column with the entire values.

```
data = data.drop(['ID'],axis=1)


del df['ID']
```

I tried both these methods, however when I save the new data to same file and reopen it, I realize it only removed the column name ("ID") but not the values. And its written "Unnamed" instead of "ID" when I read it in the console.

```
--data.csv file
,Index,Height,Weight
0,1,167,51
1,2,181,61
2,3,176,69
3,4,173,64
4,5,172,65
--data.csv file
```

And this is how it looks in the console:

```
       Unnamed: 0  Index      Height     Weight
0               0      1      167        51
1               1      2      181        61
2               2      3      176        69
3               3      4      173        64
4               4      5      172        65
```

I want to remove the entire column with the values. Is there a method for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is not really a column that is being saved, it is an index -- something every dataframe has. To save a dataframe into a csv without the index, use

```
df.to_csv('file', index = False)
```

to read from csv (initially while you are sorting it out and it is still there in the file) you can do

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', index_col = 0)
```

once you get rid of the index you can read simply without mentioning `index_col` which is equivalent to

```
df = pd.read_csv('file', index_col = None)
```

when you `print` a df it will still show you the index

Comment: Yes, it worked. I know it looks stupid because I named it as "ID" to try to delete it since there wasn't any given name for that column in the original file. Thank you a lot.

Comment: had the same problem myself! glad it is sorted